# jquery .slideToggle() horizontal alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

slideToggle does exactly what I want, only I want the slide to be horizontal.

I now have an horizontalhide/show and animation on click, but I would like to have the toggle options. So that when I click on the active link, it will play the animation reversed and hide itself.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AFWNA/826/ A little update to @BlackSheep answer.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use the `animate` method:

```
$('#element').animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZBQa/

Comment: Jeah this is what I wanted, thanks for the answer. I still don't really comprehend the { width: 'toggle'} statement. You've set the width in css, but display to none. So jquery then displays the element and animates the given width?

Comment: @ThomasCS Those properties are not required, I just added them for the demo and yes, jQuery animates the width, if the element is hidden, jQuery animates the width and show it and vice versa.

Comment: But I still have to give each button a different class or id, because else one button would toggle the other?

Comment: @ThomasCS Well, that is related to selector and logic behind your code, if you want to animate multiple elements you can add class attributes to them.

Comment: ai, just found out that its not working 100%. The links all load into the same iframe, so I'm animating the iframe. And they animate each others iframe...

Comment: @ThomasCS For this you can post another question.

Comment: @undefined , here the left portion is static and the toggle is happening from the right side , can it be made in such a way that the right remains static and toggles from left .

Answer (score 4):

Created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/RqWk2/

```
$("div").animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

Comment: ah right, but I want it to be the other way around, that it will pop up when I click something.

Comment: Instead of `width: 'toggle'` you cold use `width: '200px'`

Comment: but then it wouldn't toggle anymore?

Comment: I tried to use '200px' but it doesn't display the div, even if I set the style width to '0px' it now would always display the div and just blink each time I click the buttons with the onclick events.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear in the assumptions I was making for what you might understand, I start out with div being display:none and nothing happens when I try and set it's width to 200px.   Then if I make the div displayed and try setting the width to be 0px it just blinks to 0 then right back again to full size.

Comment: I take it you no longer care about this.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, to use jquery ui. See
[api jquery ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/)
but it may not be always useful as it has its glitches

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne0gspzz/4/) to see the glitch, it does not move all the rest elements smoothly.
I put here code, but it should be used with jQuery UI 1.10.3.

js

```
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle('slide');
});
```

css

```
.t {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div id="toggle" class='t'>1</div>
<div id="" class='t'>2</div>
<div class='t'>3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to toggle between two width's you could do something like below :

```js
$('#A').click(function(){
if($(this).width() > 20){
$(this).animate({width: '20px'})
}
else{
$(this).animate({width: '50%'})
}
});
```

```css
#A{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
}
#B{
  min-height:300px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
</div>
<div id="B">
<span>Some stuff</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this, and works great!

html code:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS
        /* flip the pane when hovered */
        .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

i use this inside a bootstrap col-sm-* and works great too

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="content-box flipper">
                        <div class="content-box-front">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope content-box-icon"></span>
                            <h4>Share your emotions</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-box-back">
                            <p>Share emotions with friends, family and teammates.</p>
                            <button>Read more</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the css

```
.content-box
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-box-icon
{
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 15px auto;
    color: #fff;
    float: none; 
    background:#25acfd                     
}
.content-box-front
{
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
}
.content-box-back
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed it to be continuous, you can set up setTimeinterval as follows

```
<?php
setInterval(function (){
$('div').animate({width: 'toggle'});
},200);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

**I wanted the Height to toggle so I used**(I used in my project)

```
function show_hide(target){
 var x = document.querySelectorAll("." +target);
 var y = $( x ).next()
 $(y).animate({height: 'toggle'});
}
```

Comment: Why not use .slideToggle(), the function the original question is asking a vertical replacement for?