# How to hide and show div with special effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With reference of Mr.Vytautas Butkus,
I have used his code, Using his code I can get vertical effect but I want horizontal effect of show and hide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var $content = $(".content").hide();
      $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $content.slideToggle();
      });
    })
```

So please Suggest me what can I do for Horizontal hide and show effect of div?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/show/ slide?

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470081/jquery-slidetoggle-horizontal-alternative

Comment: Thnaks mishik and Sudhir, I saw both links I thing it will work for me let me test..!

Comment: hey,I am used $('#contents').toggle( "slide" ); It work fine on chrome but not on IE.

Comment: @AloNE Try using `$('#contents').animate({width: 'toggle'});` works more fine in IE, chrome and FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slideToggle does slideUp and down.  So use `.animate()` instead of `.slideToggle()`

You can use

```
$('selector').animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

Your code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
          var $content = $(".content").hide();
          $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
            $content.animate({width: 'toggle'});
          });
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toggle( "slide" )` like this:

```
      var $content = $(".content").hide();
      $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
         $content.toggle( "slide" );
      });
```

**[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qa8b2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by expanding width.
If you don't want to use jQuery.animate function then you can also do this by using CSS3 transition property.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user1671639's response.

But, for a smoothest animation on iPad, you can also use the excellent [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to create the animation in CSS3 simply.

And add a fall back on normal JavaScript animation for old browsers including IE9.