# JQuery .toggle('slide') not sliding it looks more like .show() or .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a button that when clicked displays an animation were two triangles slide in, but when I try to use the .toggle('slide') command it does something that resembles .show() or .hide(), also it takes 2 clicks to do everything and I want it to work in 1. I put my JQuery below but my full code is in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JoshuaHurlburt/pen/gppyqM) or this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLna1wop/) I recommend looking at the CodePen one because the JSfiddle is having problems for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttondiv').click(function(){
    $('#triangle').toggle('slide', 'slow');
    $('#triangle2').toggle('slide', 'slow');
  })
});
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny it doesn't look any different.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dyqr3tbg/3/

Comment: How about `slideToggle('slow')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttondiv').click(function(){
    $('#triangle').animate({"margin-left": "0px"}).show();
    $('#triangle2').animate({"margin-left": "0px"}).show();
  });
});
```

```css
/*body {
  background-color:gray;
}*/

#buttondiv {
  background: blue;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0px;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  font-size:25px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-45px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  border:none;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 35px 0 35px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-100px;
}

h1 {
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  bottom:28px;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 5px red;
}

#triangle2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 35px 0 35px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>
  <div id='buttondiv'>
  <div id='triangle2'></div>
  <div id='triangle'></div>
  <h1>Click</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that way .. may it help .. you can try using opacity in css and animate() in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttondiv').click(function(){
   if($(this).find('#triangle').css('opacity') == 0)  {
      $('#triangle,#triangle2').animate({'opacity': 1},1000);
   }else{
        $('#triangle,#triangle2').animate({'opacity': 0},1000);
   }
  });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLna1wop/2/)

Comment: I want to it look like it is sliding though not fading

Answer (score -1):

the jquery function toggle does not have a 'slide' parameter, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in the docs, so instead of :

```
$('#triangle').toggle('slide', 'slow');
```

try just:

```
$('#triangle').toggle('slow');
```

Comment: I have tried that, then it just makes it look like a .fadeIn() or .fadeOut() effect instead of sliding.

Comment: have you ever try with animate?

Comment: @Joshua, I don't think that the kind of animation that you are looking for for your button, matches with the animation that you  can do with .toggle()...

Comment: I found that: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470081/jquery-slidetoggle-horizontal-alternative], see if it helps:

Comment: I tried it on my code but it still is looking like .show()