# Jquery horizontal slide toggle

Tags: jquery

I want to make an element horizontally collapsible. I've found a solution here:
[other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470081/jquery-slidetoggle-horizontal-alternative)
This is exactly what I want, but wit a little difference. I want my element to initially be in the collapsed state, and expand it by a button click. Any ideas?

**edit:** 
`collapsible.animate(width: "toggle"}, 1000);` Looks good ,the only problem is when my element is expanded, it should have `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block` what is the default set by `.animate(width: "toggle"}`

Answer (score -1):

```
$(element).animate({width: 'toggle'}, function() {
    $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the animation plays while `$(element)` being displayed as `block` and after the (false) animation ended, it changes to `inline-block`. And collapsing back not working this way for me.

Comment: Please add description to your answer. We are voting to delete this question because of its **length** and **content**.